# jQuery dynamic form display on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onchange

I'm using the following jQuery function to show a specific form on selection of a value in a select box.

```
<script>
$("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
})
</script>
```

The select option value is matched with the form id. The problem I'm facing is that on the first onchange event, the code works alright. But on subsequent onchange events, the new form is appended onto the existing form. For instance, if I select #xyz option, then the #xyz form is rendered. But now if I change my select option to #abc, the #abc form is appended to the #xyz form.

If a user changes his selection, the original form should be removed and then the new form should be rendered. For example, if I choose #abc option after choosing #xyz option, the #xyz form should be removed, and the #abc form should be displayed in its place.

```
<select id="selectCategory" name="category" style="width:100%;" tabindex="1">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="book">Textbooks/Course Material</option>
        <option value="compexam">Entrance Exam Books</option>
</select>

<form class="upload" id="book" onsubmit="return checkUpload();" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
<form class="upload" id="compexam" onsubmit="return checkUpload();" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none" >
```

I hope this was comprehensible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
$("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
    $("form").hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
})
</script>
```

First you need to hide the form and then show form which you want.

In your case, You are only showing the forms means each time one form will display and will append with other.

Comment: Thanks! Have no idea why this didn't occur to me!

Answer (score 1):

You should hide the other forms then...

```
<script>
$("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
    $("form").hide(); //Hide all forms first
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show(); //Show only what you want
})
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks! Have no idea why this didn't occur to me!

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You can hide all the other forms first then show only the specific target form after the event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
        $("form").hide();
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Have no idea why this didn't occur to me!

Comment: No problem! You can also add a class to the form in case you have other types of forms in the same page

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/g2cdygd0/

JS:

```
$("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
    $('.formShownBySelect').hide();
    $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

HTML:

```
<select id="selectCategory">
     <option value="xyz">XYZ</option>
     <option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>

<form id="xyz" class="formShownBySelect">
     <label>I'm form XYZ</label>
</form>

<form id="abc" class="formShownBySelect">
    <label>I'm form ABC</label>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#xyz, #abc {
     display: none;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#selectCategory").on("change", function() {
  $(".showable").hide();
  $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="showable" id="div1" style="background-color: #f00; display: none;"></div>
<div class="showable" id="div2" style="background-color: #0f0; display: none;"></div>
<div class="showable" id="div3" style="background-color: #00f; display: none;"></div>
<br>
<select id="selectCategory">
  <option value="">-- please choose --</option>
  <option value="div1">Red</option>
  <option value="div2">Green</option>
  <option value="div3">Blue</option>
</select>
```